# How do I get a turbo-boost at the start of the race?

Tags: sonic-and-sega-all-stars-racing

In one of the loading screens, a tip says "Hit ACCELERATE at just the right moment during the countdown to get a TURBO-BOOST start":
[image]

When's the "right moment" and what are techniques or tips to increase the chances that I hit the accelerate button at the right moment? Does the "right moment" differ per racer character? If yes, please state the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oooh! I just read this, which is why i asked about it in my iPad question. I don't know about the answer for the  iPad, but I read about [the answer for this one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/960422-sonic-and-sega-all-stars-racing/answers?qid=170446):

> Push 'acceleration' between '3' and '2', it should work. If it fails
>   on the first try, experiment with the timing between those seconds.
>
> BTW, the slower (less accel and high speed) chars don't seem to turbo,
>   but they get a boost anyway, just not to pole position.

I don't have  the pc/console version though, so I cannot test the reliability of the two answers.