# iPad Sonic Racing - how do I accelerate at the start of the race?

Tags: ios, sonic-and-sega-all-stars-racing

In Sonic and the Sega All-Stars Racing (iPad port. Oh, well, probably technically iOs port), you cannot "accelerate" - the game does that for you automatically.

At the  same time, when I time-race, I can see the "ghost" version of myself takes off at the beginning of the race. I did a bit of reading, and found that in the console versions of the game you can "accelerate" at the start if you hold the accelerate button at the start of the race.

Is there some alternative to do this on the iPad?

Comment: If it's anything like the iPhone, it should accelerate automatically. The yellow button is supposed to be for drifting/turbo boost. I don't have an iPad so I can't speculate on that.

Comment: By "accelerate" at the start of the race, do you mean an extra "boost" at the start, like what I asked for in my question about Sonic & SEGA All-Stars Racing (but for the console/PC): [How do I get a turbo-boost at the start of the race](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/65692/4797)?

Comment: yes! that is it, the extra boost. (I'm aware that i don't need to do anything to make the  car accelerate, because, well, it just accelerates)

Comment: @bharal You might want to edit your question to mention that you you want to know how to do a 'turbo boost' at the start of the race, instead of 'accelerate'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so. I just tried holding down the yellow button in as many ways as I could, and I only accelerated after the race started.